# Unable to login to Oracle Database from OSX

Tags: oracle, oracle-client

I've downloaded and installed Oracle Instant Client on my Mac Sierra.
I have also created the tnsnames.ora files and exported its path.

However, when I try to login to the remote Oracle server, I get the following error:

```
Mridulas-MacBook-Pro:~ mridulaprabhu$ sqlplus demo$security/password@ERPONWEB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Aug 18 16:37:03 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

When my colleague connects to the same server using the same credentials on windows, he can login.

Someone told me it could be because of the characterset on my MAC. So I have set NLS_LANG to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII` but it still doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X is a Unix variant, and you're running this from a shell. So the `$` in your username is being interpreted as an environment variable.

If you do:

```
echo demo$security/password@ERPONWEB
```

you'll see that it only shows `demo/password@ERPONWEB` - unless you happen to have an envorinment variable called `security`, in which case that will be substituted.

You can escape the dollar symbol to stop that interpretation:

```
sqlplus demo\$security/password@ERPONWEB
```

or enclose the entire argument in single (*not* double) quotes:

```
sqlplus 'demo$security/password@ERPONWEB'
```